# SiriKit app getting "App installation failed" error while installing app

Tags: ios, sirikit

Error,

> This app or an app that it contains has a Siri Intents app extension that declares values in its IntentsRestrictedWhileLocked key's array value that are not in its IntentsSupported key's array value (in the NSExtensionAttributes dictionary in the NSExtension dictionary in its Info.plist).

I have added one item in `IntentsRestrictedWhileLocked`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the solution is, any Item which is in `IntentsRestrictedWhileLocked` items must be in `IntentsSupported`.

This will ask user to unlock iOS device first to perform action of this Intent `INPayUsingApp`.
[image: Pay using app]

> In the `IntentsRestrictedWhileLocked` key, add a String item for each intent for which you require the device to be unlocked. Set the value of each item to the class name of the intent.

This will ask user to unlock iOS device first to perform action of this Intent.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add IntentsRestrictedWhileLocked in both Siri and SiriUI Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with an WatchOS Intents Extension. 
In my case on the iOS Intents Extension I wasn't supporting all Intents that I was on the Watch. After changing the Info.plist of the iOS Intents extension target it started working.

So for those who are building a WatchOS Intents extension, make sure to support all Intents you plan to support on Watch OS on iOS as well.